# Common Package instead of Library in Dart?

Tags: dart

I have some model classes shared between different dart projects.

## Option 1

First, I followed the dart Library convention to do the following:

**In the project/package which imports the common lib/package:**

- pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  mycommon:
    path: ../mycommon
```

- some_class.dart:

```
import 'package:mycommon/models.dart';
```

**the common lib/package:**

- pubspec.yaml

```
name: mycommon
```

- lib/src/model/model_1.dart
- lib/src/model/model_2.dart
- ...
- lib/src/model/model_50.dart
- lib/models.dart:

```
library mycommon;

export 'src/model/model_1.dart';
export 'src/model/model_2.dart';
...
export 'src/model/model_50.dart';
```

## Option 2

Treat the common lib as a normal package

**In the project/package which imports the common lib/package:**

- pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  mycommon:
    path: ../mycommon
```

- some_class.dart:

```
import 'package:mycommon/model/model_1.dart';
```

**the common lib/package:**

- pubspec.yaml

```
name: mycommon
```

- lib/model/model_1.dart *(no library keyword)*
- lib/model/model_2.dart
- ...
- lib/model/model_50.dart

I don't find anywhere using **Option 2** yet. This is just what I came up with by myself.

My question is simply if the **Option 2** way is recommended? I prefer using the **Option 2** because I can just import what class I actually want instead of everything. And most of time, I will only need one class model per dart file.

Comment: `(no library keyword at all. just a normal class)` What does that mean? Where did you get the idea of naming a file `.class`?

Comment: @NateBosch thanks for the reply. That was just a typo. I have changed my question description now.

Answer (score 1):

`lib/src/model/model_a.class` isn't a file name you should ever use for Dart code. The file should be `lib/src/model/model_a.dart` regardless of what type of Dart code it has.

It's perfectly fine to use `lib/model/model_a.dart` and import as `package:mycommon/model/model_a.dart`. The *usual* case is that a package is published with a single library that gets imported, and then implementation detail in `lib/src`, but that isn't a requirement. If there are bits of implementation that are useful on their own, having them outside of `lib/src` and imported directly is fine.

I'd recommend *not* following that pattern if there are many such files, or if a bunch of them commonly need to be imported together. `import 'package:mycommon/models.dart';` is going to be a lot nicer than dozens of imports in a row for each individual model. Dart is not Java and every class you import does not need to be in it's own library.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer. Your suggestion is based on a bunch of classes commonly need to be imported together for a dart file. That is not the case in my question. For a dart file, I only need to import one model, but the lib has about 50 models. For example, `business_1.dart` will only need `model_1.dart` and `business_2.dart` will only need `model_2.dart` etc... In such case, do you still suggest I import 50 models all together to `business_1.dart`? Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what else will need to import `model_1.dart` and `model_2.dart`. If `business_1.dart` and some other code _near_ it is what needs to import it, then putting it next to that file would make the most sense. This strikes me as potentially an unusual way to organize code. In general I don't usually try to put "business" code all together, then "model" code somewhere else. I'd group all the `_1` related code, (business, model, view, whatever) near eachother.

Comment: The name `business` is just an example name. I just gave a bad example, I think I should change the example name `business` to `view`. Besides, model can be shared btw different projects, but not the view. eg: in mobile, the view is flutter code. In web, the view is angulardart. That's why I need to create a separate model package lib instead of "near eachother". I want to reuse the model code for many different projects instead of putting them near eachother. All is about code sharing. I will put them near eachother if this is a single project, but it's not.